# python install without pip on ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ubuntu, pip

I need to install a Python package in a custom Docker container that I'm building from the official 'ubuntu' Docker image, so I want to minimize how much space this uses. Python3 installs fine and runs, but for some reason, pip is not included.

So I installed via `apt install python3-pip`, this works but it is a whopping 300 megs and takes a couple of minutes to install (apparently because it installs a sh*load of stuff to build binary packages from gcc etc).

Of course I could uninstall python3-pip from the image after installing the dependencies I want, and additionally use `apt autoremove` to get rid of 299 megs. However this takes another minute.

So although the above works, it significantly increases the build time of my Docker image. So I tried to see if there was a way of installing the dependency without pip:

I tried downloading the dependency's `.tar.gz` from PyPI, extracted, and tried `python3 setup.py install`, but this gets me an odd error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 59, in <module>
    from distutils import log
ImportError: cannot import name 'log'
```

I thought perhaps I need to install setuptools, or upgrade distutils.

I tried to use `get-pip.py` from the official site but that failed too:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 20890, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip._internal
  File "/tmp/tmpjpa5gs_x/pip.zip/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpjpa5gs_x/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpjpa5gs_x/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpjpa5gs_x/pip.zip/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 17, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpjpa5gs_x/pip.zip/pip/_internal/locations.py", line 10, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'sysconfig'
```

which is very weird because if I start python3, `import sysconfig` works fine.

I also tried `apt install python-pyyaml` (the dependency I need in my Docker image) but that doesn't seem to exist.

So I'm out of options.

Comment: `pip` actually really needs all this (the C compiler and other build tools) because pip packages might contain C code or link with binary packages.

Comment: Yes I know why these are necessary to cover all possible build/install cases, just seems overkill for one or 2 libraries which don't need C (AFAIK). There should be a "light" version of pip that is for pure Python packages, it would probably be 1/100 the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is no `apt install something` that is available for a python package, here is how to do it. Thanks to @Anthon and @digitalarbeiter as their answers provided important information to arrive at solution.

- To install ***via a setup.py file*** (esp. useful in Ubuntu Docker container):

  - it was sufficient for me to

    ```
    apt install python3-distutils
    <download package, tar xvf, cd to folder>
    python3 setup.py install
    ```
  - This method of installation only works for pure Python packages (should not not be a surprise), which means that Python packages that have non-pure Python dependencies may not install or, if they do, will have some functionality unavailable.
  - Note that even *before* installing python3-distutils, `python3 -m distutils` worked; this implies that the builtin distutils, that comes with Python3 via `apt install python3`, is not the full distutils; I did not know that, is this fact ever mentioned anywhere?
- To ***install pip without the gcc toolchain***: it was sufficient for me to

  ```
  apt install python3-distutils
  wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
  python3 get-pip.py
  ```

  Then `pip install pyyaml` completed. It seemed to install from a `.tar.gz` so it is the pure Python implementation too. Not surprising. This technique is useful if a package is not installable via `apt install python3-<package>`

The above methods required only a few megs of disk space.

A couple other missing pieces of the puzzle for me were:

- `apt install python3-<something>`:

  - I missed the fact that many Python packages are distributed this way in Debian, handy for packages that have a C implementation (or C dependencies) since no compilation necessary.
  - AND I didn't know that for packages that are called `py<something>` on PyPI, the apt install is `python3-<something>` NOT `python3-py<something>`. Unfortunately `apt search pyyaml` was no help here.
- `apt search <something>`: I had sort of forgotten about it because bash on (desktop) Ubuntu automatically suggests the right package to download when a command is not found.

  - In particular `apt search yaml` yields 81 packages that provide YAML read/write in several languages (Python 2, Python 3, nodejs, Java, Go, Ruby, Erlang, Lua, Perl, C, C++, Clojure), linter, schema validator, etc.
  - Multiple search terms are AND'ed so `apt search yaml python3` showed the python3-yaml that I missed.
  - Unfortunately `apt search pyyaml` produces no results, *eventhough* the `Source` and `Homepage` fields of `apt show python3-yaml` contain the word "pyyaml". I could not find a way to make `search` include those fields.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a similar issue and wanted to give an alternative solution.

On Ubuntu 20.04 build-essential and python3-dev are recommended packages for [python3-pip](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-pip), therefore you can use the `--no-install-recommends` option to skip them:

```
RUN apt update -y && \
    apt install python3 python3-pip --no-install-recommends -y && \
    apt clean
```

This took my image from 420MB to 165MB, and obviously the build time was also quicker.

**Note**: this will work fine for pure-Python packages, but you will likely need build-essential and python3-dev if you want to compile anything

### Useful links

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-pip
- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt-get.8.html

Answer (score 2):

The Debian and Ubuntu package for PyYAML is called `python-yaml`, not `python-pyyaml`.

```
sudo apt install python-yaml
```

or

```
sudo apt install python3-yaml
```

respectively.

(It seems to be common in Debian/Ubuntu package names to drop any additional "py" prefix that a Python package might have: it's `apt install python-tz` instead of `python-pytz`, too. They don't seem to like the py-redundancy.)

Comment: +1 for a way to completely obviate the need for installing pip, I did not know that! but my question still stands: if you have a pure Python package, is there a way to install without full pip like just setuptools or something, I was hoping the errors in my question give hints about something I did wrong.

Comment: I added answer that address that addresses the question for cases where a python-something apt install does not exist

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 this is not providing the Python module for me. Has the package name been changed since 2018?

Answer (score 1):

I have been installing `pip` from the `pip-get.py` in Docker (Ubuntu) containers for a few years without problem. For me it is the best way to not-get pip-out-of-date warnings or (at some point, some time ago) SSL related errors.

So the second part of your answer is close, but your python install seems a bit too minimal, you need `sysconfig` as provided by `python-distutils`. You can try this rather minimal `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

MAINTAINER Anthon

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  python3 \
  python3-distutils \
&& apt-get clean \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# this gets you the latest pip
COPY pip/get-pip.py /tmp/get-pip.py
RUN python3 /tmp/get-pip.py

RUN pip3 install pyyaml
```

which I ran using this `Makefile`:

```
doit:   pip/get-pip.py
        docker build .

pip/get-pip.py:
        -@mkdir pip
        curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o pip/get-pip.py
```

(those need to be TAB characters on the indented lines) to make sure `pip-get.py` is available from the context (you can of course download it from within the Dockerfile, but that is not necessary). That ends in a succesful PyYAML install, but it will be slow.

I recommend you start using ruamel.yaml (disclaimer: I am the author of that package), by changing the last line of the Dockerfile to read:

```
RUN pip3 install ruamel.yaml
```

Apart from many bugfixes in the original PyYAML code it is based upon, `ruamel.yaml` supports YAML 1.2 **and** YAML 1.1 (replaced in 2009 and the version  PyYAML supports), and installs the appropriate version from a `.whl` file, so you'll have the fast C loader available in your container (PyYAML doesn't do that).

You can load a YAML file using the C-loader in `ruamel.yaml` using:

```
from pathlib import Path
from ruamel.yaml import YAML


path = Path('yourfile.yaml')
yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
data = yaml.load(path)
```

Comment: The first error in your question is also caused by `python-distutils` not having been installed in your container.